# VBA debug works fine but error when running

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I've recently been teaching myself VBA with the goal in mind to make my own custom "site crawler" in order to make a site index/ site map.

So my code (when completed) will look through and click on all links on a website.

I am able to acquire all links from the homepage no problem, and place them in Excel. However when I try to get the links from other pages, I get runtime errors such as :

> "Runtime Error '70': Permission denied"

or

> "Runtime Error '91': Object variable or Width block not set"

HOWEVER when I go in debug mode, and Step Into the code, I don't run into any of these errors. It is quite strange.

One thing to mention, I am accessing the website from a system with many security settings including restrictions on internet which is why I have the line: `CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`
instead of `Create(internetExplorer)` ,etc...

It gets stuck at the `For Each tabLinks In ieLink2` in my code below. I have removed the links, but hopefully everyone can still get the idea..
(please note, I am new to StackOverflow so I'm not sure if it's proper to post the whole code like this, or if I am supposed to post only a piece of my code).

```
Public Sub CreateSiteIndex_Click()

    'Variables
    Dim objShell     As Object
    Dim objShellWind As Object
    Dim ie           As Object
    Dim ieFol        As Object
    Dim ieData       As Object
    Dim ieLink       As Object
    Dim tabData      As Object
    Dim ieLink2      As Object
    Dim listLinks    As Object
    Dim tabLinks     As Object

    'Variable for duplicate link check
    Dim dupCheck     As Boolean

    'Variables to check for site links
    Dim siteCheck    As Boolean
    Dim siteAddress  As String
    Dim siteAddress2 As String

    'Variables to check for unwanted links
    Dim noCheck      As Boolean
    Dim noCheckLink  As String
    Dim noCheckLink2 As String

    'Track Shell Windows
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWind = objShell.Windows

    'Navigating to webpage
    Set ie = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate2 "mywebsiteURLisHere(just blocked it out for security purposes"

    Set ieFol = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    'Wait until page is loaded before checking links
    Do Until ie.ReadyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    'Get all links from webpage and store as a list/array
    Set ieData = ie.Document
    'tabData(0) = 0

    Set ieLink = ieData.getElementsByTagName("a")

    'These are specifications/filters for which links to allow in the Excel sheet
    siteAddress = "specific filter here"
    siteAddress2 = "another one..."

    noCheckLink = "another filter"

    'For Loop - goes through each link on page
    i = 1
    j = 1
    k = 1
    Cells.Clear
    For Each listLinks In ieLink
        'Checks to make sure no duplicates before adding link to Excel sheet
        'dupCheck becomes TRUE if duplicate
        Range("C1").Select
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            If (ActiveCell = listLinks.href) Then
                dupCheck = True
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.WrapText = True
        Loop

        'If not a duplicate
        If (dupCheck = False) Then
            'Check that link is a Horizons link
            sC = InStr(listLinks, siteAddress)
            sC2 = InStr(listLinks, siteAddress2)
            'Check that link is not HOME or TOP OF PAGE
            nC = InStr(listLinks, noCheckLink)

            If sC > 0 Or sC2 > 0 Then
                siteCheck = True
            End If

            If nC > 0 Then
                noCheck = True
            Else: noCheck = False
            End If

            'If link is a Horizons link AND it not linking back to homepage
            If (siteCheck = True) Then
                If (noCheck = False) Then

                    'Add links to Excel sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = listLinks.href
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = listLinks.innerText

                    'Convert URL to hyperlink
                    For Each Cell In Selection
                        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 3), Cell.Value
                    Next

                    If ieFol Is Nothing Then Set ieFol = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

                    'Follow hyperlink
                    'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
                    ieFol.Navigate2 ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value

                    While ieFol.Busy
                        'wait for page to load
                    Wend

                    Set tabData = ieFol.Document
                    Set ieLink2 = tabData.getElementsByTagName("a")

                    For Each tabLinks In ieLink2

                        If ieFol Is Nothing Then Set ieFol = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

                        If tabData Is Nothing Then Set tabData = ieFol.Document
                        If ieLink2 Is Nothing Then Set ieLink2 = tabData.getElementsByTagName("a")

                        ActiveSheet.Cells(k, 7) = tabLinks.href
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(k, 6) = tabLinks.innerText

                        If ieFol Is Nothing Then Set ieFol = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

                        If tabData Is Nothing Then Set tabData = ieFol.Document
                        If ieLink2 Is Nothing Then Set ieLink2 = tabData.getElementsByTagName("a")

                        'Check for broken link
                        If InStr(tabData.Body.innerText, "Page Not Found") > 0 Then
                          'The link is not valid, flag the cell
                          ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
                        End If

                        'ie.Quit
                        k = k + 1

                    Next tabLinks
                    'Next

                'Skip link if it links back to homepage
                ElseIf (noCheck = True) Then
                     i = i - 1
                End If
                siteCheck = False
            'If link goes to external site, put it in a different column
            ElseIf (siteCheck = False) Then

                ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 5) = listLinks.href
                ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 4) = listLinks.innerText
                j = j + 1
                i = i - 1

            End If

        'If it is a duplicate, skip that link
        Else:
            dupCheck = False
            i = i - 1
        End If

        i = i + 1

    'On to the next!
    Next listLinks

    'Close the window when done
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Another note, it goes through the aforementioned for loop but doesn't always get stuck at the same point. Sometimes it will get stuck on the 2nd iteration, sometimes the 4th. But never when debugging.

Comment: When you have this kind of errors while working with the Internet is _almost always_ due to the Internet connection that is not able to load the full content of the webpage within the waiting time you give it. For example, I've noticed that after navigating a link you will 1) wait for IE status being released from Busy; 2) wait 5 seconds starting from now. I fear the problem is that this time is not enough for the page to fully load, so getting errors afterwards.

Comment: P.s. this is the reason why in Debug mode always works: in Debug mode it's you controlling the speed, and human speed is much lower than the connection one; on the other side, run-time speed is much faster than the connection's one. As the problem might be a bit anywhere, what I suggest you to do is to increase the waiting time and making sure that _every time you call a page load_ (i.e. Navigate), just after you put a time-waiter for waiting 5-10 seconds depending on your computer and the network speed.

Comment: IMO, VBA is about the worst choice you could make for this task. You would have a much better experience in c# or VB.Net with the System.Net.HttClient class. And you would find more help available.

Comment: @Crowcoder I second that. You can certainly write a crawler in VBA, but you are going to make yourself miserable. If you want something easy to learn, try Python.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thank you so much for your comments! you were correct, the pages must not have been finished loading. I'm running it now with no problems so far but it is taking an extremely long time (of course, because I added 5 seconds each time it opens a page). This website has many many pages so it might be running for a while.

Comment: @Crowcoder You're probably right, it's been very tough so far using VBA.. The reason I chose it was because the site I want to crawl has many restrictions so I have to run an external script and store the results somewhere (like Excel, in this case). Then I would export the results to put onto the website. Would that be possible in C# or VB.Net?

Comment: @NickBailey See my comment to Crowcoder above; Would that kind of thing be possible to do in Python? I am actually better at Python than VBA, i've been learning it too.

Comment: @Jessica yes, it is trivial to work with Excel, especially when using [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) . I'm not sure what restrictions you are talking about, but HttpClient class can do authorization, cookies, certificates, etc. if you need it.

Comment: @Crowcoder The website is formatted in such a way that only the top admins can access the main css and change the structure, etc. So what I can do is limited in regards to what I can change on the website. (That's all I meant by restrictions) . So I just need a simple way to gather the links and place them into a page on the website where the site index will go. ( Although now I can see that my way isn't very simple after all!)

Comment: @Jessica the easiest part of VBA is that is perfectly interfaced with Excel and other Office applications, but at the same time the implementation of classes is very poor. On the other hand, Python is very well implemented to interact with the web, but on the other hand the implementation with Office applications and Microsoft systems (in my opinion) might lead to headache before to get it sorted. I would go for C# or VB.NET, that have several classes you can use much easily for your task and at the same time they live natively in the .NET framework.

Comment: @Jessica I have no experience with it, but maybe get the best of both worlds with [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thanks for the explanations! I'll have to look into both of those options. -This might be a silly question but what kind of program do I need to write and run C# or VB.NET?

Comment: @Crowcoder That looks really interesting! I didn't know that existed. Will have to look into this too!

Comment: @Jessica you can find the free releases of Visual C# Express 2010 (for C#) and Visual Basic Express 2010 (for VB.NET) on [Microsoft download area](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_4). If you feel more confident with "VBA-like" languages and less confident with C-Java like languages, then I suggest you to choose VB.NET; apart for some advanced differences, C# and VB.NET are like Italian and French (same structures, verbs, roots, names...  just different way of writing them).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ great to hear that they are available for free! Normally I'd say  i'm better with java type languages, but since i've started this project in vba, it will probably be easier for me to continue in that line of thinking

Comment: Thanks again, everyone for all your comments. I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: So, I spoke to my supervisor about a week ago and he said I have to use a program that already comes with our computers (I can't download anything even if it's free). So looks like i'll be stuck with VBA :(

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone who are looking for another solution. I have faced similar problem today. Then I used "DoEvents" before the lines that were highlighted with errors, and it works.